# Vite server displays blank page on localhost

Tags: vite

I am using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) and have started the server using the `npm run dev` command. The server apparently then starts, and does not show any errors. But navigating to localhost only shows a blank page.

I checked the route path and it is correct, but I still get the same blank page. The localhost does not open even though I used the TypeScript command.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you specified the port when accessing your localhost link. The default port for dev in  vite is 5173.(http://localhost:5173)

If you are on the right address check if there is any error messages in the console: Open the dev tools in your browser (F12) and navigate to the console tab and reload the page, see if any errors pop up.